# Encounter error when re-ask the user to grant permission to my app

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, pre-authentication

While testing integration of the new Facebook API with my iOS app, I removed the app from my Facebook account's app settings, expecting that to force Facebook.authorize() to re-ask the user to grant permission to my app. I encounter error: An error occurred with app_name, Please try again later.

Steps:

1. Login Facebook via pop up dialog. And it works well.

   [fbSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) { ...}];
2. I removed the app from my Facebook account's app settings.
3. Open my app and login facebook again, it encounter error.[image]
4. And if I click Okay button, it directly to my facebook web. Instead of closing the pop up dialog.
   [image]

Comment: Facebook has resolve this problem. please refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/135521366593458?browse=search_505856e728eaf8113786373